# Comparing .end() against a value

Tags: c++

I'm writing a board game with an bizarre layout so I have a `map` from a point to the places's value. If the place is empty it isn't in the map therefore if `find` returns `end()` the place is empty. If I want to check what a particular place's colour is i use the following. Is this code valid? Or in other word is it safe to compare `end` against `lColour`

`enum COLOUR {BLACK,WHITE}`

`this->mBoard.find(Point(p.x - 1, p.y))->second == lColour`

where `lColour` is of type `COLOUR`

Comment: What value do you think `end()->second` would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you're doing is not safe. The past-the-end iterator (the one returned by `end()`) cannot be dereferenced. You're doing `->` on the result of `find()`: if that result is past-the-end, you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: What would the chances of it returning `true` be?

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that you are going to write a program that only works if you get lucky?

Comment: @user2049175 About the same as returning `false`. In the sense that it's *totally random behaviour.*

Answer (score 2):

No.

You should check that the iterator returned by find != end before trying to get the second element.

```
const auto& point_color = this->mBoard.find(Point(p.x - 1, p.y);
if (point_color != this->mBoard.end() &&
    point_color->second == lColour) {
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not because it would mean dereferencing the end iterator and that is undefined behaviour.